# Building Connection string to dl layer and configuration manager issues

Tags: c#, dapper

I have an issue I share my dl layer through a winforms application and now wanting to share it through a .net core application but the problem I have come across is that the configuration manager is not handled the same as it uses app settings.  What I was thinking to get away with the minimal of changes was to do the following. I am using dapper and .net core 3.0

In My Constructor have my context as follows so that if I want to pass the connection string down from the API layer I can and this means I would be only making the change the one place in my already stable context layer I am using ado.net and dapper.

Is this a solid method or would there be a better way of retrieving the connection string so I don't have to make any changes to the data layer.

I miss the old xml files made things so much easier.

```
public OMSContext()
{
    constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataConnectionLive"];
}
public OMSContext(string ConnectionForApi)
{
    constr = ConnectionForApi;
}
```

Comment: Trying to dodge technical dept usually does not pay off well in the end. If you want a solid approach then follow the SOLID principles. You'd be surprised at how the current "problem" would have been a non-issue as it would have allowed your code to transition to different platforms without coupling.

Comment: I do not think you understood my statement about technical *debt* (typo). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt

Comment: It was an open statement and not meant to be a slight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question however having a static configuration class is a popular way of doing this.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static String ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

This is instead of using configuration manager elsewhere in the application. To access the properties anywhere you can just do `Config.ConnectionString`.

To actually populate the `Config` class, you can specify separate classes to populate them and run it in the start up. For standard .NET:

```
public class ConfigSetup
{
    public static void SetupConfig()
    {
        Config.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    }
}
```

For .NET core in Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration _config { get; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _environmentPath = env.ContentRootPath;

    _config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath).AddJsonFile("appSettings.json").Build();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    Config.ConnectionString = _config["ConnectionString"];
}
```

So you may have several `ConfigSetup`s for each project type but only need to run the one which is relevant to the current project. This will mean you will keep the code the same everywhere apart from the startup.

Comment: That will work for .net framework but what about .net core where the configuration manager is not valid in .net core 3

Comment: @rogue39nin I've added some code which can read from appsettings.json in .NET core